# FF extension to create sidebars from bookmark folders

Tags: firefox

I'm looking for a FF extension that will allow me to create additional sidebars for organization of my bookmarks, similar to what an extension called Update Scanner creates for itself.  It creates its own sidebar that contains only the bookmarks that pertain to it.

I'd like to have one sidebar that only contained bookmarks for work, one that contained only bookmarks for a project I'm working on, one that contained only bookmarks for whatever else, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this add-on: [SideBar Bookmark Selector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sidebar-bookmark-selector/). You can put all your booksmarks in different folders and use this add-on to see them.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but this seems only to allow choosing whether to show Bookmarks Toolbar, Bookmarks Menu, and/or Unsorted Bookmarks in the built-in bookmarks sidebar.  However, the page references an add-on called Flat Bookmarks which looks closer to what I need, but it doesn't seem to allow folders chosen to be "permanent" sidebars.  Thanks anyway.